# Copy canvas pixels from a 2D context to another - Javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl

In javascript, I am writing an audio buffer to a canvas for spectrum visualisation. I am currently working with the audio signal and pasting on a 2D context of a canvas. I want to make a similar effect to the OpenGL GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE, copy a vertical pixel line (the last on the right) and extend it as lines in another 2d context.

```
function init() {
  copyvals();
  requestAnimationFrame(init);
}
requestAnimationFrame(init);

var ctx = spectrocanvas.getContext("2d");
var imageData = ctx.getImageData(spectrocanvas.width-1, 0, 1, spectrocanvas.height);
var data = imageData.data;
var _ctx = othercanvas.getContext("2d");
_ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
```

What's the best way to do this? with a lot of ctx.strokestyle?
Thanks in advance

Effect example:

[image: example from online documentation]

Answer (score 1):

[WebGL (1.0)](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/) is based on [OpenGL ES 2.0 API](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.pdf).

`CLAMP_TO_EDGE` is a valid argument for the texture parameters `TEXTURE_WRAP_S` and `TEXTURE_WRAP_T`, in OpenGL ES 2.0 as well as in WebGL 1.0.

For instance:

```js
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```